# Text transition loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to slide/loop between texts showing one text at a time but it doesn't work as intended. Here's a recreation of it: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tender-ully-wgjjvf

Comment: Please add more context, what did you intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is

```
top={`-${currentIndex * 100}%`}
```

current index increases, "top" of your slider gets more big minus values.
there should be a way to rest this every slide change.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (currentIndex === texts.length - 1) {
      const resetIndex = setTimeout(() => {
        setCurrentIndex(0);
      }, interval);

      return () => clearTimeout(resetIndex);
    }
  }, [currentIndex, texts, interval]);
```

This reset part is not needed because the module function will take care of the continuous increment issue.

Working code for your problem + [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/stupefied-panna-9cnypf?file=%2Fsrc%2FSlider.tsx%3A16%2C1)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Box, Heading } from "@chakra-ui/react";

interface SliderProps {
  texts: string[];
  interval?: number;
}

export const Slider: React.FC<SliderProps> = ({ texts, interval = 2000 }) => {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [isTransitioning, setIsTransitioning] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const sliderInterval = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentIndex((prev) => (prev + 1) % texts.length);
    }, interval);

    return () => clearInterval(sliderInterval);
  }, [texts, interval]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsTransitioning(true);
  }, [currentIndex]);
  const handleTransitionEnd = () => {
    setIsTransitioning(false);
  };
  // Reset index to 0 when reaching the end of the texts array
  /*useEffect(() => {
    if (currentIndex === texts.length - 1) {
      const resetIndex = setTimeout(() => {
        setCurrentIndex(0);
      }, interval);

      return () => clearTimeout(resetIndex);
    }
  }, [currentIndex, texts, interval]);
*/
  return (
    <Box h="100px" overflow="hidden" position="relative">
      <Box
        //key={currentIndex}
        position="absolute"
        top={!isTransitioning ? "-100px" : "0"}
        transition="top 0.5s ease-in-out"
        width="100%"
        display="flex"
        flexDirection="column"
        onAnimationEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
      >
        <Heading
          bgGradient="linear(to-r, #a0e1fd, #59c5f4 , #b593ff)"
          bgClip="text"
          size="2xl"
          fontWeight="medium"
        >
          {texts[currentIndex]}
        </Heading>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```